# Command executes from command line but not from CRON

Tags: cron

I'm a beginner I hope you can help me.
I have a wordpress development server and I have to change a value in a mysql db every night.

The command I use is the following, and it works via command line.

```
mysql -u root -pMYPASSWORD MYDB --execute="update DB_options set option_value = 'https://dev.example.com' where option_id = 1"
```

However, if I use this command in CRONTAB it is not executed and I have no error messages in the log.

```
40 4 * * * root mysql -u root -pMYPASSWORD MYDB --execute="update DB_options set option_value = 'https://dev.example.com' where option_id = 1"
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank's for any help, there is so much to learn!

Answer (score 1):

Om `cron` the command must be:

```
40 4 * * * mysql -u root -pMYPASSWORD MYDB --execute="update DB_options set option_value = 'https://dev.example.com' where option_id = 1"
```

But will be wise to create dedicated shell script with the command and include your profile variables as PATH for example

Comment: Thanks Romeo but the command doesn't got executed without root at the beginning.
Any idea?

Comment: @EVEMilano, how do you add it in cron, via `crontab -e`?

Comment: I edit the file /etc/crontab

Comment: @EVEMilano, in such case you need the user (`root` in this case). But try via `crontab -e` as `root` user